# Why am I getting %%memit syntaxerror?

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I have installed memory profiler, but I am getting a syntax error when I try to use it.

My code:

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
%%memit 
i=0
```

My error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-34-34835ac53431>", line 3
%%memit
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is the link where information about memory profiler is given but unfortunately yet I couldn't debug it:
https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Comment: Please try to provide more context of what the goal is and what you're using the memory profiler for, and provide code prior to the error as @desertnaut suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running the load and memit magic commands in the same cell caused issues. Try running the code in 2 separate cells:

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
```

```
%%memit 
i=0
```